# How to dynamically create a SQLAlchemy engine and use it between requests in Flask?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I'm building an API using Flask that will allow user to query multiple databases at once. It is supposed to work like this:

1. User first "connects" to their databases by submitting the URIs. The frontend will send these URIs to the backend through a request.
2. User can then interact with the databases. The frontend will translate the user's actions into SQL queries and send them to the backend to execute over their databases.

My current plan is to implement an API view to handle creating SQLAlchemy engines and a different API view to handle the querying (i.e. executing raw SQL using the SQLAlchemy engines). But I'm not sure how to share the SQLAlchemy engines between different views and requests.

Comment: The flask-sqlalchemy package supports binding to multiple databases - you could take a look at how they do it.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know ahead of time how many database connections the user need, so I need to set up the SQLAlchemy engines dynamically through an API view.

Answer (score 1):

Web apps can run in different processes or even different machines. So the idea that once the used registers their engine, you will create a "global variable" and be happy is generally speaking wrong. It may work in some scenarios but it does not have to. Even if you have 1 process deployment it may happen that the process is restarted and you loose your runtime data. So what now?

The main question is: Where do you want to store the URIs of the engines? One possibility (and I suggest starting with that one because you are already familiar with databases) is to store the data in some Main Application's database.
Or if you want to learn something new, try memcached or redis.

Then you can use some kind of application-level registry (or configuration - not sure how it is called in flask, but in really it is a global object), which can contain the constructed engines. If the engine is not in the registry, add it. If it is, just use it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Storing the DB URIs from the user on the main app's database/memcached/redis does make sense. The issue is that whenever the user query on their "registered" DBs, the API view must load the URIs, create new database engines and set up new DB connections. This chain of operations seems quite expensive.